# Salesforce1 - Disable pull to refresh

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have a form that I use to view in SF1 app. Whenever I write something and accidentally pull down, it refreshes the everything. Is there an option to turn off the pull to refresh or is there a code to make it disabled?
I found a similar code

```
targetEl.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
```

but this does not work. It stop all scrolling from happening.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have faced similar issue today and after a bit of research I have found complete code in github to address the concern. Please review the below link for code. It worked for me.

https://github.com/JitendraZaa/LightningExamples/tree/master/RendererDemo